# Problem sending broadcast message to inactive app

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, broadcastreceiver

I have to build 2 Android Apps. The first one (MDE_App) written in Xamarin Android(8.0) and the second (RFID_App) in Xamarin.Forms(11.0)

The main app used is the MDE_App, which must be able to start the RFID_App if it is not already running in the background, initiate an RFID scan there, and then return the result to the MDE app via broadcast.

Currently, I have already written both apps as a sample app, but they do not "see" each other.
Is this even possible what I have in mind and if so can someone give me useful hints how I could implement this?
I don't need any ready made code. Maybe someone has useful tips or hints in which direction I have to think

Here are my MainActivities and BroadcastReceiver:

MainActivity RFID_App

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.OS;
using RFID_App.Droid;
using Android.Content;
using AndroidX.LocalBroadcastManager.Content;

[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(MainActivity))]
namespace RFID_App.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "RFID_App", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme",
        MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | 
        ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | 
        ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize )]
    public class MainActivity : 
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity, IBroadcastService
    {

        private static ReceiverRFID receiver;
        private IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("eu.logfox.ReceiverMDE");
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            receiver = new ReceiverRFID();

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[]     
            permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, 
                permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();
            RegisterReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
        }

        protected override void OnPause()
        {
            UnregisterReceiver(receiver);
            base.OnPause();
        }

    
        public void sendDMC()
        {
            try
            {
                string dmcCode = "]<!n4lkj3n4j3n4lj3n4kj3n4l3k4nk3j4nlkj34nklj3";

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.SetAction("eu.logfox.ReceiverMDE");
                intent.PutExtra("DMC_CODE", dmcCode);
                Context context = Android.App.Application.Context;
                context.SendBroadcast(intent);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
    }
}
```

}

ReceiverRFID

```
namespace RFID_App.Droid
{
    [BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = true)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "eu.logfox.ReceiverMDE" })]
    public class ReceiverRFID : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            if(intent.HasExtra("SCAN_REQUEST")) {
                Toast.MakeText(context, intent.GetStringExtra("SCAN_REQUEST"), 
                    ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.MakeText(context, "Any intent", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
        
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity MDE_App

```
namespace MDE_App
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = 
        true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {

        private static ReceiverMDE receiver;
        private IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("eu.logfox.ReceiverRFID");

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

            receiver = new ReceiverMDE();

            Button btnSend = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnSend);

            btnSend.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.SetAction("eu.logfox.ReceiverRFID");
                intent.PutExtra("SCAN_REQUEST", "SCAN");
                intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.IncludeStoppedPackages);
                Context context = Android.App.Application.Context;
                context.SendBroadcast(intent);
                //context.SendOrderedBroadcast(intent, "");
            };
        }
        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] 
            permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
            {
                Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, 
                    permissions, grantResults);

                base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();
            RegisterReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
        }

        protected override void OnPause()
        {
            UnregisterReceiver(receiver);
            base.OnPause();
        }
    }
}
```

My Receiver MDE_App

```
namespace MDE_App
{
    [BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = true)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "eu.logfox.ReceiverRFID" })]
    public class ReceiverMDE : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent 
            intent)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(context, "Received intent!", 
                ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to start RFID_App:

```
btnSend.Click += (sender, e) =>
{
    //Change Action to "eu.logfox.ReceiverMDE"
    Intent intent2 = new Intent("eu.logfox.ReceiverMDE");
    intent2.PutExtra("SCAN_REQUEST", "SCAN");

    PackageManager pm = Application.Context.PackageManager;
    Intent intent = pm.GetLaunchIntentForPackage(PackageName of RFID_App);
    intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
    
    SendBroadcast(intent2);
    Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
}
```

Both `UnregisterReceiver(receiver);` (MDE_App and RFID_App) are commented out:

```
        protected override void OnPause()
        {
            //UnregisterReceiver(receiver);
            base.OnPause();
        }
```

When MDE_App starts RFID_App, it will call OnPause() of MDE_App.

**Update**:

For `PackageManager`, on Android 11 and higher, you need to take into account [package visibility rules](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility) and [add a  element to your manifest](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/declaring) to declare what third-party apps you are interest in discovering or analyzing.

```
<manifest
        ...>
    ...

   <queries>
      <package android:name="com.companyname.forms"/>
   </queries>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Thank you. But when i run your code i get 
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
After this line: intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);

Comment: @DaveR Use Physical machine instead of virtual machine. I also meet this error before.

Comment: i use a physical machine

Comment: @DaveR Have you run RFID_App on the physical machine?

Comment: yes both have run on my device before for testing

Comment: @DaveR Make sure that `PackageName of RFID_App` is right.

Comment: just looked. In my android manifest of rfid_app packagename is eu.logfox.rfidapp. And this package i used.
Intent intent = pm.GetLaunchIntentForPackage("eu.logfox.rfidapp"); Or do i forget something?

Comment: @DaveR It is related to the Android version. I edited the answer, wish it can help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252076/discussion-between-daver-and-jianwei-sun-msft).